# Кто может помочь с кодом?! (срочно)(HTML)

Tags: html

Кто может помочь с кодом, как сделать страницу, чтобы по середине был текст, а по 2м сторонам от него 2 картинки!? Помогите, пожалуйста)[image: Помощь]

Comment: Нет кода, потому что не знаю, как это сделать. Нет представления. Знаю, как разделить страницу на 2 части с помощью <div>, но тут явно нужно 3

Comment: Срочно — на фриланс-биржу с оплатой пропорционально срочности.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Зачем злой такой? У всех бывает, что нужно срочно что-то сделать и таких ситуаций море, особенно когда в универе жмут, если не помогаешь, то лучше вообще ничего не писать и тем более не минусовать. минимум можно оставить команды для собственноручной попытки, но уж точно не выговаривать ему все это.

Comment: @andreymal Чтобы ему очередной недопрограммист загнул столько, сколько в ведущих мировых компаниях за час не зарабатывают, за эту работу в минуту делом? Видел уже таких

Comment: @Str у кнопки минуса есть подпись «Вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться; он непонятен или не несёт пользы» — вопрос полностью соответствует этой подписи. Поэтому минусовать вопрос **нужно**.

Comment: @Sevastopol' я больше по джава, но не специалист, а только учусь... Зашел посмотреть почему ему минус влепили и наткнулся на посты злые)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как то так.

```css
.content{
  background-color:green;
  padding-top:20px;
}
h4,
.list{
  text-align:center;
}
.box{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
 
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<h4>Выберите звуки чтобы продолжить</h4>
<div class="box">
  <div><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/68/bf/36/68bf36401bb9a56d05e92633a32dd989.png"></div>
  <div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>Звук М</li>
    <li>Звук М</li>
    <li>Звук М</li>
    <li>Звук М</li>
    <li>Звук М</li>
    <li>Звук М</li>
    <li>Звук М</li>
    <li>Звук М</li>
    <li>Звук М</li>
    <li>Звук М</li>
    <li>Звук М</li>
    <li>Звук М</li>
    <li>Звук М</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/68/bf/36/68bf36401bb9a56d05e92633a32dd989.png"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Igor Прошу прощения, я тут в первый раз.(

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div>
    <div >
      <span>Первое предложение</span>
      <span>Второе предложение</span>
    </div >
    <div>
       <div>Первая картинка</div>
       <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Звук--</li>
                <li>Звук--</li>
                <li>Звук--</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
       <div>Вторая картинка</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```